How can I modify a player's name tag using ProtocolLib or in Bukkit to achieve a bolded colored nametag?
Hello I'm developing a minecraft plugin using ProtocolLib to modify a player's name tag so that when they use a Nether Star their nametag changes. My goal is to temporarily change the player's name tag to be purple and bold for 2 minutes and then reset it back to normal. However, I'm encountering a FieldAccessException error when trying to modify the packet fields.
package me.games.weapon;

import com.comphenix.protocol.PacketType;
import com.comphenix.protocol.ProtocolLibrary;
import com.comphenix.protocol.ProtocolManager;
import com.comphenix.protocol.events.PacketContainer;
import com.comphenix.protocol.wrappers.WrappedChatComponent;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;
import com.comphenix.protocol.wrappers.EnumWrappers;
import com.comphenix.protocol.wrappers.PlayerInfoData;
import com.comphenix.protocol.wrappers.WrappedGameProfile;


import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class SuperCharge implements Listener, CommandExecutor {

    private final JavaPlugin plugin;
    private final ProtocolManager protocolManager;

    public SuperCharge(JavaPlugin plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        this.protocolManager = ProtocolLibrary.getProtocolManager();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            // Create a new ItemStack for the Nether Star
            ItemStack supercharge = new ItemStack(Material.NETHER_STAR);
            // Give the player the Nether Star
            player.getInventory().addItem(supercharge);
            return true;
        } else {
            sender.sendMessage("You must be a player to use this command.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerUse(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        ItemStack item = event.getItem();

        if (item != null && item.getType() == Material.NETHER_STAR) {
            // Apply the glowing effect for 2 minutes
            player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.GLOWING, 2 * 60 * 20, 1));
            // Change the player's name tag to purple and bold for 2 minutes
            changePlayerNameTag(player);

            // Schedule task to reset the player's name tag after 2 minutes (2400 ticks)
            new BukkitRunnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    resetPlayerNameTag(player);
                }
            }.runTaskLater(plugin, 2 * 60 * 20);

            // Remove the Nether Star from the player's inventory
            player.getInventory().removeItem(new ItemStack(Material.NETHER_STAR, 1));
        }
    }

    private void changePlayerNameTag(Player player) { // Currently isn't working and isn't coloring and bolding
        PacketContainer nameTagPacket = protocolManager.createPacket(PacketType.Play.Server.PLAYER_INFO);
        nameTagPacket.getPlayerInfoAction().write(0, EnumWrappers.PlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER);
        nameTagPacket.getPlayerInfoDataLists().write(0, Collections.singletonList(new PlayerInfoData(
                WrappedGameProfile.fromPlayer(player),
                1,
                EnumWrappers.NativeGameMode.fromBukkit(player.getGameMode()),
                WrappedChatComponent.fromText(ChatColor.BOLD + "" + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + player.getName())
        )));
        try {
            protocolManager.sendServerPacket(player, nameTagPacket);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void resetPlayerNameTag(Player player) {
        PacketContainer nameTagPacket = protocolManager.createPacket(PacketType.Play.Server.PLAYER_INFO);
        nameTagPacket.getPlayerInfoAction().write(0, EnumWrappers.PlayerInfoAction.UPDATE_DISPLAY_NAME);
        nameTagPacket.getPlayerInfoDataLists().write(0, Collections.singletonList(new PlayerInfoData(
                WrappedGameProfile.fromPlayer(player),
                1,
                EnumWrappers.NativeGameMode.fromBukkit(player.getGameMode()),
                WrappedChatComponent.fromText(player.getName()) // Original name without formatting
        )));
        try {
            protocolManager.sendServerPacket(player, nameTagPacket);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


I tried using Spigot's API for teams but it only colors the player's name tag with one color and doesn't work for multiple like bolding on top of it.
Now I am trying to use ProtocolLib to modify the player's name tag but I am encountering this error in the server console. I just want to be able to edit the player nametag and color it with multiple colors, what ever way is possible but these are the only ways I have thought of and tried.
[ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerInteractEvent to Weapon v1.0-SNAPSHOT
com.comphenix.protocol.reflect.FieldAccessException: Field index 0 is out of bounds for length 0
    at com.comphenix.protocol.reflect.FieldAccessException.fromFormat(FieldAccessException.java:49)
    at com.comphenix.protocol.reflect.StructureModifier.write(StructureModifier.java:315)
    at me.iplaygames.boostweapon.SuperCharge.changePlayerNameTag(SuperCharge.java:80)
    at me.iplaygames.boostweapon.SuperCharge.onPlayerUse(SuperCharge.java:60)
    ...


Looking at the source code of class StructureModifier, accessors is an empty List.

Which version of MC are you using ? Since 1.20.4 if I well remember, there is changes in this packet class

@Elikill58 I am using 1.20.4

Since Minecraft 1.19.3, some packets about player informations changed.
Now, the PlayerInfo packet have been rename to PlayerInfoUpdate (in ProtocolLib, it's the same for compatibility reasons). To remove, it's now PlayerInfoRemove.
To add content, you should use the PlayerInfoUpdate with some specific options as described here, in the Players actions.
You should use PlayerInfoData like this:
// create a new player info data
PlayerInfoData new_playerinfo = new PlayerInfoData(playerInfo.getProfileId(),
                playerInfo.getLatency(), playerInfo.isListed(), playerInfo.getGameMode(),
                playerInfo.getProfile(), new_tab_name, playerInfo.getProfileKeyData());

// write it into packet
nameTagPacket.getPlayerInfoDataLists().write(1, Collections.singletonList(new_playerinfo));

